# Jersey 2 with Jackson serialisation issue

Tags: jersey-2.0, weblogic12c, jackson2

**Tools :**

Weblogic 12c

Jersey 2.21.1

Jackson 2

```
public class Profile implements Serializable
{

    private List<Status> orderStatus;

    public void setOrderStatus(List<Status> orderStatus)
    {
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
    }

    public void getOrderStatus()
    {
        return orderStatus;
    }
```

I have a simple POJO class as above. 
I am facing below issue while using `Jersey 2 with Jackson`.

1)When Profile class is serialised , the JSON gets created as  : `{"OrderStatus":[{}]}`

2)So the key generated is `OrderStatus` and not `orderStatus`

3)When this JSON gets de-serialised , it throws error -

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "OrderStatus" since it cannot 
find field with OrderStatus but has field as orderStatus

I have tried adding : 

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY,getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
```

hoping that serialisation will only use fields as a key (and will not use property) and JSON will be generated as `{"orderStatus":[{}]} .`

But it is not working and same error is thrown. 
Is there any way we can serialise POJO with key as fields and not properties.

Can anybody please help here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure `orderStatus` is the name use specific [JsonProperty](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) :

```
 @JsonProperty("orderStatus")
 public void getOrderStatus()
```

> @JsonProperty (also indicates that property is to be included) is used to indicate external property name

Comment: So Jackson will use getter method only to serialise and not use fields ?

Comment: @Atul Jackson will find JsonProperty for this field and use its value for externalize the field